# calculate runtime offset from runtime address minus readelf function address?

Tags: android, crash, shared-libraries

I'm trying to analyse a crash in my android app which calls a function in a shared object outlined as android java->jni->ndk->shared object. I went through the page:

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash

However, I don't get such nice dumps as in the examples. I only have a stack trace and some lines in the logcat:

stack:

```
art_sigsegv_fault 0x0000006f2a44b58c
art::FaultManager::HandleFault(int, siginfo*, void*) 0x0000006f2a44b3f8
art::SignalChain::Handler(int, siginfo*, void*) 0x00000071c40cc328
<unknown> 0x00000071ec845668
__cxxabiv1::set_registers(_Unwind_Exception*, _Unwind_Context*, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::scan_results const&) 0x0000006e893c8c90
::__gxx_personality_v0(int, _Unwind_Action, uint64_t, _Unwind_Exception *, _Unwind_Context *) 0x0000006e893c8c78
__cxxabiv1::set_registers(_Unwind_Exception*, _Unwind_Context*, __cxxabiv1::(anonymous namespace)::scan_results const&) 0x0000006e893c8c90
::__gxx_personality_v0(int, _Unwind_Action, uint64_t, _Unwind_Exception *, _Unwind_Context *) 0x0000006e893c8c78
unwind_phase2 0x0000006e8c8f8d40
_Unwind_Resume 0x0000006e8c8f8e10
interpreter::combine_nodes(std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, node_info const&, node_info const&) 0x0000006e8c8737c0
yy::parser::parse() 0x0000006e8c81dc98
hi(char const*, char const*, unsigned char, char const*, char const*, _JavaVM*, _jobject*, char const*, unsigned char) 0x0000006e8c822988
::Java_com_bitroller_hi_MainActivity_jhi(JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jstring, jstring, int, int) jhi.cpp:20
art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline 0x0000006f2a2d4048
<unknown> 0x0000006f2a2d4390
```

logcat:

```
2022-08-03 10:46:56.600 2770-2770/com.bitroller.hi A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x6e8c909e60 in tid 2770 (om.bitroller.hi), pid 2770 (om.bitroller.hi)
2022-08-03 10:46:56.647 3108-3108/? A/libc: failed to exec crash_dump helper: Operation not permitted
2022-08-03 10:46:56.648 927-927/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1659516416.643:128328): avc:  denied  { ptrace } for  pid=3108 comm="om.bitroller.hi" scontext=u:r:runas_app:s0:c57,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c57,c257,c512,c768 tclass=process permissive=0 SEPF_SM-A725F_12_0001 audit_filtered
2022-08-03 10:46:56.664 2770-2770/com.bitroller.hi A/libc: crash_dump helper failed to exec, or was killed
2022-08-03 10:46:56.665 2770-2770/com.bitroller.hi A/libc: failed to wait for crash_dump helper: No child processes
```

So I thought about:

1. taking the address of the function I know i.e. interpreter::combine_nodes() from the stack trace
2. checking the address of that function by readelf in the shared library
3. subtracting the address in 2) from the address in 1) i.e 1)addr - 2)addr
4. subtracting the address I get in 3) from the failure address in the stack trace i.e. 0x0000006f2a44b58c - 3)addr
5. check the address I get in 4) by addr2line and identify the line in the source of the shared library where the program failed

Does this make sense? Currently, I just tested what I get if I use addr2line on an address of the function mentioned read by readelf but it returns ??:0. Does anyone have any hint what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out after two months of investigation (one before reporting this and one after that) that this unwinding problem only occurs if the native code is cross-compiled by a standalone toolchain. I had the chance to import the cpp source code of the library that crashes in android studio, compile it there and there's no more crash during unwind.